# Rails form with URL constructed dynamically using one of its fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am building a search form that has a text input and a submit button (doh!). My `routes.rb` file contains:

```
get ':dependency', to: 'pages#dependency'
```

This means that whatever I put after `/` will route to `PagesController#dependency`, having `params[:dependency]` set to whatever string is set in the URL.

I would like to build a form that, upon submission, will go to `/<value-from-text-input>`, dynamically using the value supplied in the text input. How can I do this? It would be great if I don't have to use JavaScript.

Comment: This is a bad idea - your route will swallow any other get routes unless it is declared last. Also what is the actual use case for this? It sounds pretty useless - if you know the path to a resource than just tack it on in the address bar. But your users don't anyways.

Comment: If you what you want is to create a real search function in a blog/site like rails app that is a whole tutorial or even a book in itself. However this naive implementation is not really viable. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not saying this will be going to production. I was just testing different approaches and I was curious whether this is possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is a simple form action.

```html
<form action="/" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="dependency"/>
</form>
```

Because Rails is configured on the root '/' this will submit the form at a get action, appending the values to the end as a query string, which rails then converts to the cleaner route.

Comment: it's make a route to the `/?dependency=<value-from-text-input>` root with parameters, but OP wants route with parameters in url like `/<value-from-text-input>`.

Comment: make your route get '/:dependency', to: 'pages#dependency' with starting slash.

Comment: And how would I link the dynamic field value to the form URL?